# VoiceOver behavior when using UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, accessibility, uisplitviewcontroller, voiceover

**Overview**

When using a `UISplitViewController` and then presenting a new detail controller, or pushing another VC onto the detail controller's nav stack, the navigation item on the master controller is activated.

**Example 1**

Let's say the master controller has a title of "Settings" and contains a table view with multiple rows that when tapped will load a new view controller into the details pane using `showDetailViewController`. The detail pane is properly updated but VoiceOver jumps to the navigation item of the master pane, so we hear "Settings".

Now we can call `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.view)` in `viewDidAppear` of the view controller we're displaying but we'll still hear "Settings" a moment before. Moving where we post the accessibility notification into `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` does not make a difference.

**Example 2**

Similarly if we push another view controller onto the nav stack of whatever controller is in the detail pane "Settings" once again gets activated.

---

Now the iOS Settings (on iOS 11) app handles this differently. When you select an item in the list the first cell on in the view on the detail pane is read correctly, and the "Settings" navigation item is not read. How can I mimic this behavior?